# SQL - ORDER BY ASC LIMIT 1 excludes multiple same results - best method?

Tags: mysql, sql, limit

I'm still learning SQL so I was wondering if there is a better way of doing the following.

I need to get row data for the lowest and highest values in a column (lets call it columnA).
I would use:

```
SELECT *
  FROM table
 ORDER BY columnA
  DESC LIMIT 1
```

Problem is I get only one result due to the `LIMIT 1` but there may be identical lowest / highest values in ColumnA that have different values in the other columns. I need those other rows too.

There is `SELECT(MAX)` but I believe that will also only produce one row of data.

The ways I can think do this are by putting the highest / lowest columnA values into a variable and then back into a second query `OR` use a `LEFT JOIN` on alias tables to do this in single query but is there any more direct method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way is to perform a sub-query:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE columnA = (SELECT MAX(columnA) FROM MyTable);
```

You can even query both extremes at once:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable
WHERE columnA = (SELECT MAX(columnA) FROM MyTable);
   OR columnA = (SELECT MIN(columnA) FROM MyTable);
```

I haven't tested the next one (don't know if MySQL supports `UNION` in
sub-queries), but it should work as well, might be a bit more
efficient (depending on your data size).

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable
WHERE columnA IN (
    SELECT MAX(columnA) FROM MyTable
    UNION
    SELECT MIN(columnA) FROM MyTable
);
```

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you so much. I didn't mention I was using PHP to pull data out of the rows to build an array of information so i'm probably better off with individual rows for MIN/MAX if I don't know the number of duplicates (although I suppose I could always COUNT them). The first solution is absolutely perfect and really simplifies my code. I'm sure all the variations will come in useful in future applications and for other members so your thorough answer is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is :

```
SELECT * 
FROM MyTable m1 
WHERE not exists (select 1 from MyTable where columnA > m1.columnA)
```

Comment: I'm going to give this a go now but I have to admit I'm confused by what is actually happening here.

Comment: @James Pitt - the `where` condition says - give me rows , such that not exists any row with greater value - i.e. give me only rows with max value..

Comment: You are very kind. Thanks for explaining this and providing an intriguing alternative. I have to accept an answer so I am going to go with the code I have chosen to use from Soulmerge's answer.